# When is the game actually auto-saved in R&C: Rift Apart?

Tags: ratchet-and-clank-rift-apart

Whenever I try to leave the game, it says that all my unsaved progress will be reverted to the last checkpoint, but what does that mean exactly? This game does not have any manual save so it's not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the events that trigger an auto-save in Rift Apart:

- Travel to a different planet
- Buying a new weapon from Mrs. Zurkon
- Picking up a collectible (Gold Bolt, Infobot, Lorb or Craiggerbear)
- Enter a new named area
- Travel through a dimensional rift